# DAX - Meassure that sums only the first occurance by group

Tags: dax, azure-analysis-services

I'm trying to figure out how to build a measure that sums a total, but only taking the first non-empty row for a user.

For example, my data looks like the below:

```
date    user  value
-----------------
1/1/17  a     15
2/1/17  a     12
1/1/17  b     null
5/1/17  b     3
```

I'd therefore like a result of 18 (15 + 3).

I'm thinking that using FIRSTNONBLANK would help, but it only takes a single column, I'm not sure how to give it the grouping - perhaps some sort of windowing is required.

I've tried the below, but am struggling to work out what the correct syntax is

```
groupby(
    GROUPBY (
        myTable,
        myTable[user],
        “Total”, SUMX(CURRENTGrOUP(), FIRSTNONBLANK( [value],1 ))
    ),
    sum([total])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have much luck getting `FIRSTNONBLANK` or `GROUPBY` to work exactly how I wanted, but I think I found something that works:

```
SUMX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(myTable[User]),
            "FirstDate",
             CALCULATE(MIN(myTable[Date]),
                       NOT(ISBLANK(myTable[Value])))),
        "FirstValue",
         CALCULATE(SUM(myTable[Value]),
                   FILTER(myTable, myTable[Date] = [FirstDate]))),
    [FirstValue])
```

The inner `ADDCOLUMNS` calculates the first non-blank date values for each user in the filter context.

The next `ADDCOLUMNS`, takes that table of users and first dates and for each user sums each `[value]` that occurred on each respective date.

The outer `SUMX` takes that resulting table and totals all of the values of `[FirstValue]`.